# Use Razor templates to generate HTML files

Tags: c#, html, .net, templates, razor

I want to create a CLI tool which uses the Razor template engine to generate HTML files without using a webserver.

Can this be achieved? All documentation that I found so far mentions the usage of Razor in the context of a web application using ASP.NET or Blazor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that can be achieved. We using `RazorEngine` in WindowsService to generate user emails.

see: http://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/#RazorEngine

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Unfortunately, that project is unmaintained for 5 years. I'd prefer an "official" solution to that one.

Comment: Please, let me know if you found more elegant solution.